# Xcode Like log with NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nstextview

I'm trying to set up a NSTextView like the console in Xcode (or pretty much any other IDE available). That being the user cannot edit the NSTextView, however they can put in a character when appropriate, I'm trying to set up that same functionality. No clue how to go about it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply make an action that appends a formatted string containing a line break, a time stamp, and your desired text to the text view. Here's an example:

```
- (void)addToLog:(NSString *)input
{
    [[self.myTextView textStorage] appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@: %@",[NSDate date],input]]];
}
```

So then instead of using `NSLog(@"some text");` you could call `[self addToLog:@"some text"];` and it would be added to a new line in your text view.

Comment: This is what I've done with the log function, but I need to take input data. So I need to be able to only enter in characters in the NSTextView at a certain time, and reject all input at other times. Isn't there a delegate method to take a character in or something?